# Load a class using reflection then edit the variables during runtime

Tags: java, class, variables, reflection, runtime

Okay, so I have a java file which is loading another class and I want the java file to be able to edit and read variables from the class which is running.

For example: 
   I have a button which when pressed it sets a variable (This is the class file). I want the java file which is loading this class to be able to see the new value of the variable read it, set it and do whatever is needed. And I want the new value which is set to show up on the running java class.

This is what I have tried so far but when I try to edit the values like getting baseX it doesn't show up on the running class. Also, the baseX value should change when I do stuff on the running class but the stuff is not printed to the screen when I change them. It's as if reflection can't read stuff on runtime. So what does?

```
Class c = Class.forName("Client");
        for (Method m : c.getMethods()) {
            if (m.getName().contentEquals("main")) {
                Object[] passedArgs = { args };
                m.invoke(null, passedArgs);
            }

        }
        Object instance = c.newInstance();

        Field baseX = c.getField("baseX");
        Field loggedIn = c.getField("loggedIn");

        boolean gotValues = false;
        while(!gotValues) {
            boolean loggedin = loggedIn.getBoolean(instance);
            if(loggedin) {
                System.out.println(baseX.get(instance));
            } else {
                System.out.println(loggedin);
                loggedIn.setBoolean(instance, true);
            }
        }
```

Also yeah getter/setter methods would work if they worked on runtime and I could make it so that when button x is pressed variable y changes on screen. What is a java bean? Also what if I wanted to just invoke a method and not get a value? Or what if I wanted to add my own methods/code?

Comment: What have you tried and where is your problem? So far you've just stated what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sounds like you want to write a Java bean with some getter and setter methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Client {
  public Object baseX = new Object();
  public boolean loggedIn;
}
-----
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class c = Class.forName("Client");
    /*for (Method m : c.getMethods()) {
      if (m.getName().contentEquals("main")) {
        Object[] passedArgs = {args};
        m.invoke(null, passedArgs);
      }

    }*/
    Object instance = c.newInstance();

    Field baseX = c.getField("baseX");
    Field loggedIn = c.getField("loggedIn");

    boolean gotValues = false;
    //while (!gotValues) {
      boolean loggedin = loggedIn.getBoolean(instance);
      if (loggedin) {
        System.out.println("Logged in!");
        System.out.println(baseX.get(instance));
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("NOT Logged in!");
        System.out.println(loggedin);
        loggedIn.setBoolean(instance, true);
        System.out.println(loggedIn.getBoolean(instance));
      }
    //}

  }
}
```

Comment: Basically I have it so when I click login and log into the game It logs me in but when I try to use reflection to check the loggedIn boolean it still says I'm not logged in, even though I am. It's as if It's not reading the program im running.

Comment: Guy! You're not setting value to "gotValues". Another problem you could have check, whether you're running your program from within of single thread. And also one more thing: use debugger!