# Load a class using reflection and edit the variables during runtime

Tags: java, class, variables, reflection, runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load a class using reflection then edit the variables during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387482/load-a-class-using-reflection-then-edit-the-variables-during-runtime)

Okay, so I have a java file which is loading another class and I want the java file to be able to edit and read variables from the class which is running.

For example: 
   I have a button which when pressed it sets a variable (This is the class file). I want the java file which is loading this class to be able to see the new value of the variable read it, set it and do whatever is needed. And I want the new value which is set to show up on the running java class.

This is what I have tried so far but when I try to edit the values like getting baseX it doesn't show up on the running class. Also, the baseX value should change when I do stuff on the running class but the stuff is not printed to the screen when I change them. It's as if reflection can't read stuff on runtime. So what does?

```
        Class c = Class.forName("Client");
        for (Method m : c.getMethods()) {
            if (m.getName().contentEquals("main")) {
                Object[] passedArgs = { args };
                m.invoke(null, passedArgs);
            }

        }
        Object instance = c.newInstance();

        Field baseX = c.getField("baseX");
        Field loggedIn = c.getField("loggedIn");

        boolean gotValues = false;
        while(!gotValues) {
            boolean loggedin = loggedIn.getBoolean(instance);
            if(loggedin) {
                System.out.println(baseX.get(instance));
            } else {
                System.out.println(loggedin);
                loggedIn.setBoolean(instance, true);
            }
        }
```

Also yeah getter/setter methods would work if they worked on runtime and I could make it so that when button x is pressed variable y changes on screen. What is a java bean? Also what if I wanted to just invoke a method and not get a value? Or what if I wanted to add my own methods/code?

Comment: Why you ask [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387482/load-a-class-using-reflection-then-edit-the-variables-during-runtime) again?

Comment: Because no one answered the first one.

Comment: Asking again isn't appropriate, rather edit the first question with the additional information.

Comment: Who would go back to a thread or question again if the first time it didn't have the stuff required. Ask yourself, how many times have you visited the same question or website.

Comment: @RyanGlen: Your assumption of how SO works is incorrect.  Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) - of particular interest to you will be [this section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Comment: @RyanGlen So, I'm assuming you read the FAQ entry. Make sense now? Assume ppl are trying to help, not just be difficult.